# INTERSECT ALL not working on PostgreSQL 11

Tags: sql, postgresql, intersect

The PostgreSQL operation `INTERSECT ALL` does not seem to work. What am I missing?

The following query returns just one row containing the value two, but I am expecting two with the value as I am using `intersect all`.

```
(
   (select 1 as z) 
   union all 
   (select 2 as z) 
   union all 
   (select 2 as z)
) 
intersect all 
(select 2 as z)
```

Does anyone have a guess?

Comment: Unrelated, but: there is no need to put each query of a UNION between parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one row (with a value of `2` for the column `z`) in the second operand to `INTERSECT ALL` so only that one can be used to find a matching partner in the other operand.

Add a second row to the second operand of the `INTERSECT ALL` and you'll have two rows in the result.

```
(SELECT 1 z
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 z
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 z)
INTERSECT ALL
(SELECT 2 z
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 z);
```

Or you might instead want a join.

```
SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT 1 z
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 2 z
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 2 z) x1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT 2 z) x2
                       ON x2.z = x1.z;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works in all version, not just 11.

The single value of '2' on the right side of the `INTERSECT ALL` is consumed upon matching, and can't match multiple times.

Do you really want `WHERE EXISTS (..)` instead?